# Is there a Bluetooth earphone that can control the Music being played?

Tags: bluetooth, music, music-player, earphone, earpiece

I'm looking for a bluetooth earphone set, or a device compatible with it, so that I can control the music (play/pause & next/previous) without actually touching the phone.

Is there any hardware that does this? The reason is, I'm getting home from work, in a crowded bus, standind, trying to hold on with one hand, and the other hand cannot reach into phone, unlock the screen, find the next button and press it. It's too hard :)

Or any way to use the volume button for previous / next ? This would be much cheaper, and fancier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a shopping question, which is off-topic here, but as a general answer: Yes, it's possible to change tracks from Bluetooth headphones.

Almost all headphones that support [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile), which is required for better quality music streaming, can also handle [AVRCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29) (Audio/Video Remote Control Profile) which handles controlling the playback.

As an example, I have a [Samsung SBH-170](http://reviews.cnet.com/headsets/samsung-sbh170-bluetooth-stereo/4505-13831_7-32407169.html), which has buttons for play/pause, next/previous track, volume up/down and call answer.

Just check that the headphones you're going to buy support A2DP, and most likely they support AVRCP as well.

Comment: Alternatively, there exist bluetooth dongles for regular headphones/earphones, like [this one](http://www.antecmobileproducts.com/product_detail/148), which are much cheaper and allow the use of whatever existing audio gear you have.